# How do I make text be aligned to the top left of the text input field?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I want:
[image: my mockup]

What I am getting after writing code:
[image: a screenshot]

```css
// Import thingys :)
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
$primary-color: #205072;
$secondary-color: #329d9c;
$alt-color: #56c596;

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loginContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.coverImage {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  width: 75px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.subText {
  inline-size: 25em;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

//emailBoxLabel?
.mailbox,
.enterPassword {
  width: 582px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, .5);
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.emailSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.maillabel {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="emailcontainer">
  <div class="emailSection">
    <label for="email" class="maillabel">Your E-Mail Address:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="mail@website.com" class="mailbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLgmf8sj)

Comment: It is happening because you have  align-items: center; to the .emailSection class. Maybe move the label tag out of the emailSection?

Comment: @VladimirVladimirov if I dont do that it does this: https://ibb.co/cCj826P

Comment: If I move it out of the emailSection, what on earth would that do??!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erase the `flex`-settings for your `.emailsection`  element and make it an `inline-block`instead, which you center inside its parent using `text-align: center`. Make the `label` a `block` element to fill the full width of its parent (which is determined by the input field below it) and use `text-align: left;` on it.

So your settings for these three elements should be:

```
.emailcontainer {
  text-align: center;
}
.emailSection {
  display: inline-block;
}
.maillabel {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

In action here:

```css
// Import thingys :)
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
$primary-color: #205072;
$secondary-color: #329d9c;
$alt-color: #56c596;

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loginContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.coverImage {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  width: 75px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.subText {
  inline-size: 25em;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

//emailBoxLabel?
.mailbox,
.enterPassword {
  width: 582px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, .5);
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.emailcontainer {
  text-align: center;
}
.emailSection {
  display: inline-block;
}
.maillabel {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="emailcontainer">
  <div class="emailSection">
    <label for="email" class="maillabel">Your E-Mail Address:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="mail@website.com" class="mailbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bravo, thank you so much - you are a lifesaver, greatly appreciate it <3

-SimsRedux Team

Comment: Johannes, I tried to basically but another text field exactly the same way as this one but it doesn't work - it puts them next to each other. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for it to align on left :

```
.maillabel {
    text-align: left;
  width:100%;
  margin: ;
  padding : ;
}
```

Add `margin` and `padding` according to need .
As you can see in below snippet it is working .

```css
// Import thingys :)
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
$primary-color: #205072;
$secondary-color: #329d9c;
$alt-color: #56c596;

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loginContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 1080px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.coverImage {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  width: 75px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.subText {
  inline-size: 25em;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

//emailBoxLabel?
.mailbox,
.enterPassword {
  width: 582px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(142, 142, 142, .5);
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.emailSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.maillabel {
  text-align: left;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="emailcontainer">
  <div class="emailSection">
    <label for="email" class="maillabel">Your E-Mail Address:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="mail@website.com" class="mailbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

The result may seem different because it is not importing this in snippet :

```
 // Import thingys :)
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
$primary-color: #205072;
$secondary-color: #329d9c;
$alt-color: #56c596;
```

But as you can see above text is aligned to left , it will also align in your website

Comment: will try now :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qLgmf8sj/ - your link . Try in this

Comment: Changed the answer now you can see in snippet text is aligned to left